# UIAlertViewでWarningが出ます

Tags: ios, swift

```
var alert:UIAlertView=UIAlertView()
alert.title="week"
alert.message=texts[indexPath.row]
alert.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
alert.show()
```

---

```
UIAlertView is deprecated. Use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert instead
UIAlertView is deprecated. Use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert instead
```

実行はできますがこの二つのワーニングが出ます。
環境はswift2.0で、iOS9.1です

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIAlertControllerを使えば、下記のように書けると思います。

```
var alert=UIAlertController(title: "week", message: texts[indexPath.row], preferredStyle: .Alert)

let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

参考になれば幸いです。

Answer (score 0):

ワーニングに書かれている通りです。UIAlertViewは現在は非推奨です。現在推奨されている方法は、UIAlertControllerを使ってアラートを表示する方法です。